# How to print asterisk triangles side-by-side in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to print 4 star triangle side-by-side using nested for-loops in python. I included the code I am using now that prints the triangles vertically, but I do not know how to print them horizontally.

```
n = 0

print ("Pattern A")
for x in range (0,11):
    n = n + 1
    for a in range (0, n-1):
        print ('*', end = '')
     print()
print ('')
print ("Pattern B")
for b in range (0,11):
    n = n - 1
    for d in range (0, n+1):
        print ('*', end = '')
    print()
print ('')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja2rv.png)

Comment: We also cannot tell you what you need to change in your code, because you didn’t show it.

Comment: Thank you! It did not copy correctly. I've included and edited my question now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @AzBakuFarid the main idea is to print every line of shapes from the top to the last together. @AzBakuFarid code had a very little mistake that you can see the corrected one below :

```
maximum = 10
a, b, c, d = 1, maximum, maximum, 1

while a <= maximum:
    print('*'*a + ' '*(maximum-a) + ' '*2 + '*'*b + ' '*(maximum-b) + ' '*2 + ' '*(maximum-c) + '*'*c  + ' '*2 +  ' '*(maximum-d) + '*'*d)
    a += 1
    d += 1
    b -= 1
    c -= 1
```

As u wanted to be with for-loops I came up with this :

```
longest = int(input())
asterisk_a = 1
spaces_a = longest - 1
asterisk_b = longest
spaces_b = 0
asterisk_c = longest
spaces_c = 0
asterisk_d = 1
spaces_d = longest - 1
for i in range(0,longest):
    print(asterisk_a * '*' + spaces_a * ' ' + '  ' + asterisk_b * '*' + spaces_b * ' ' + '  ' + spaces_c * ' ' +  asterisk_c * '*' + '  ' + spaces_d * ' ' +  asterisk_d * '*')
    asterisk_a += 1
    spaces_a -= 1
    asterisk_b -= 1
    spaces_b += 1
    asterisk_c -= 1
    spaces_c += 1
    asterisk_d += 1
    spaces_d -= 1
```

In the first line you should give the number of asterisks in the longest case.
I tried to use meaningful variable names for better understanding.

Answer (score -1):

```
maximum = 10
a, b, c, d = 1, maximum, maximum, 1


while a <= maximum:
    print('*'*a + ' '*(maximum-a) + ' '*2 + '*'*b + ' '*(maximum-b) + ' '*2 + ' '*(maximum-c) + '*'*c  + ' '*2 + '*'*d + ' '*(maximum-d))
    a += 1
    d += 1
    b -= 1
    c -= 1
```